# how to set submit buttons as options?

Tags: html, submit, html-select

I am doing a question and answer page. My question is can i use submit button as options. I have tried it but it seems to not work. Here is the code:

```
    <textarea name="questn" readonly="readonly" cols="45" rows="5">Question</textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option" value="optiona" />
    <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option"  value="optionb"/>
    <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option"  value="optionc"/>
    <input type="submit" class="myButton" name="option"  value="optiond"/>
```

What i want to do here is that when user clicks on an option it will check whether the value is correct with the answer. I dont want to use a radio button for this. I am using images as options. Is this possible?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery.

visit this page

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_submit.asp

you also must write a javascript code to trigger it when item selected/clicked

Note: use form as selector

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>radio selector example</title>
<script language="javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1-7-2-mini.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
Chose your car:
<form action="index.html" id="form_id">
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="car" value="Car1" /> Car1<br />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="car" value="Car2" /> Car2<br />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="car" value="Car3" /> Car3<br />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="car" value="Car4" /> Car4<br />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="car" value="Car5" /> Car5<br />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="car" value="Car6" /> Car6<br />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="car" value="Car7" /> Car7<br />
<input type="radio" class="radio" name="car" value="Car8" /> Car8
</form>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.radio").click(function(){
        $("form#form_id").submit(); $()
    });                    

 });

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please refrain from linking to w3schools (see http://w3fools.com for details). Although the page you linked to *might* contain correct information, there are lots of pages that do not, and linking to it gives the site credibility that it does not deserve

Comment: can i use image instead of radio buttons

Comment: also you can download project from
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8n8wl05s5v3exv1/test.rar

Comment: of course, change them and re-edit javascript codes. also after testing it don't forget accepting answer ;)